Number salad with a meaning
617181419920141
128131119
1331152419
54141131811

Your goal is to explain what number sequence should come next and what it means.

The missing sequence is:

 3521411518 and means "Ecuador"

How we know:

 There are a lot of "1"'s compared to other digits, strongly suggesting A=1 Z=26 encoding.
 Starting with "617181419920141":
 Inserting spaces yields nothing intelligible, so we are likely looking at an anagram of a word (clued by salad in the title). I was able to solve this in my head and came up with "AFGHANISTAN: 1 6 7 8 1 14 9 19 20 1 14".
 Next to "128131119". This yields all sorts of things, such as "CHALKS". So I wrote a program to list all the possibilities for these two numbers.
 "AFGHANISTAN" turns out to be the only reasonable possibility for #1. So, I searched the options for #2 and found another country, "BAHAMAS: 2 1 8 1 13 1 19"
 At this point we have a country starting with A and one with B.  Looks like a pattern of A, B - so next might be C and D...
 So for #3, "1331152419", we can go with "CAMBODIA: 3 1 13 2 15 4 9 1"
 Then for #4, "54141131811", we get "DENMARK: 4 5 14 13 1 18 11"
 Why these particular countries? Checking against a modern list of country names, each one is the very first in alphabetical order beginning with the letters A, B, C, and D.
 So what number sequence is missing? We need the next item in the sequence - the first alphabetical country beginning with E - which is "ECUADOR: 5 3 21 1 4 15 18".

But how should the digits be sorted?
Going back to the original set, we see that each item

 has been shuffled using the same pattern: [2 1 3] [5 4 6] [8 7 9]... (broken into sets of 3 "abc" and then sorted within as "bac")
 So for "ECUADOR: 5 3 21 1 4 15 18" we get "3 5 21 4 1 15 18", which (if I counted that right) is:
 3521411518!

Possibly unintended bonus came to me overnight:  This puzzle originally had a rebus tag. So what is the solution?

 Let's convert back using 1A26Z:   C E U D A O R.
 If an or is similar to an op, we get:   SEE, YOU 'DA ORIGINAL RESPONDER!


